# How to add Open Sans font to mpdf document

Tags: php, css, fonts, mpdf

I'm trying to add `Open Sans` font to my mpdf document but without success.

This is the code I added to the previous files:

In `mpdf/config_fonts.php`:

```
$this->fontdata = array(
...
    "opensans" => array( 
        'R'  => "OpenSans-Regular.ttf",
        'B'  => "OpenSans-Semibold.ttf",
        'I'  => "OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf",
        'BI' => "OpenSans-Semibolditalic.ttf"
    ),
...
);
```

In the php output file I added this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
```

I also already tried to write `font-family: opensans, sans-serif;`

I uploaded the files into the folder: `root/plugins/mpdf/ttfonts/`

I think I did everything correctly but didn't work, it use the first sans substitutive font.

Extra info:
the mpdf folder is located at his path: `root/plugins/`
the php file is creating the pdf file is located at this path: `root/template/folder/`
inside it I declared these:

```
define('_MPDF_PATH','../../plugins/mpdf/');
include("../../plugins/mpdf/mpdf.php");
```

probably there is something wrong with the paths, but I don't find the solution.

In addition I can say that If I load the `font-family: opensans, sans-serif;`, inside the example `examples/example02_CSS_styles.php` that it works correctly.

How can I solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I set `'c'` into `$mpdf = new mPDF('c');`, that force the use of **core fonts** only, excluding the external fonts loaded from me.

Problem solved